# Button Link to Google Maps not Working on Chrome

Tags: google-maps, button, href

I have a button with an address linked to it which goes as follows:

```
<button>
     <a ng-href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q={{Store.StoreAddress}}" target="_blank">

      <span ng-bind-html="Store.StoreAddress"></span>
      </a>
</button>
```

The Button directs to the address in Fire Fox when clicked opening google maps but not in Chrome 
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query={{Store.StoreAddress}}
```

Helpful links for Maps URL :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#search-action